# Separate development from deployment assets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am using some assets during my development (fake API responses and random images), and for that, I am loading some assets.
Obviously I do not want those assets to be bundled with the release APK, how do you come around doing so?

For now, I have all assets in one `pubspec.yaml`.

The end goal is to be able to run the app `flutter run` and have fake backend. I know of mocking HTTP calls, but it is very difficult to wrap a full app, so now I have two different data source (one from assets and another http-based), and I call the one depending on `kReleaseMode` value.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using blocs you need to have a class when you inject all your blocs in that class  you define a demo mode and later you create 2 main files in one you inject a production mode and in the other you inject the demo mode later you only need to configure the IDE to launch one or other and the same process to release the app

Comment: @HaironChaviano Yep I am using BloC and the problem with the source is solved as mentioned above. My problem is `pubspec.yaml` having development-only assets.

Comment: I am surprised there's no solution after almost 3 years

Comment: Yeah, I want to load a `.env` file in development and not when I push and release. It's currently causing me an error on web when it's included.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (which also seems to be an orphaned flutter issue), but solved it using a `Builder` running in the dart `build_runner` - not to be confused with the flutter `Builder` pattern for widgets (which spoils the search results). This works as sketched here:

- collect dev-resources in a separate directory out of assets (in my case `lib/devdata/`)
- create a `Builder` implementation and a `build.yaml` file
- in `build.yaml` create separate `dev_properties` that allow the builder to behave according to the build mode, i.e. either copy the files to `assets/devdata/` or delete them in `assets/devdata/` and this directory to `.gitignore`
- add `assets/devdata/` to assets in `pubspec.yaml`
- run `build_runner` either in dev or in prod mode to copy or delete the files
- consume the files in the app using `rootBundle` if they are present / catch the resulting exception if they are absent

this command invokes the build_runner in dev / release mode respectively:

```
$ flutter pub run build_runner build
$ flutter pub run build_runner build --release
```

the builder looks roughly as follows (saved in `lib/devdata/devdata.dart`):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';    
import 'package:build/build.dart';

Builder devData(BuilderOptions options) => DevDataBuilder(options);

class DevDataBuilder implements Builder {
  final BuilderOptions options;

  DevDataBuilder(this.options);

  @override
  FutureOr<void> build(BuildStep buildStep) async {
    var mode = options.config['mode'];
    var inputId = buildStep.inputId;
    var sourcePath = inputId.path;
    var targetPath = sourcePath.replaceFirst('lib/devdata/', 'assets/devdata/');
    final outputId = AssetId(
      inputId.package,
      targetPath,
    );
    if (mode == 'dev') {
      log.info('copying $sourcePath to $targetPath');
      var contents = await buildStep.readAsString(inputId);
      await buildStep.writeAsString(outputId, contents);
    } else {
      var file = File(targetPath);
      if (await file.exists()) {
        log.info('deleting $targetPath');
        file.delete();
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Map<String, List<String>> get buildExtensions {
    return {
      'lib/devdata/{{file}}.json': const ['assets/devdata/{{file}}.json'],
    };
  }
}
```

the corresponding `build.yaml` is here:

```
builders:
  test_data:
    import: 'package:my_app_package/builder/devdata.dart'
    builder_factories: ['devData']
    build_extensions: {"lib/devdata/{{file}}.json": ["assets/testdata/{{file}}.json"]}
    build_to: source
    auto_apply: root_package
    defaults:
      generate_for:
        include:
        - lib/devdata/**

global_options:
  my_app_package:test_data:
    options:
      mode: prod
    dev_options:
      mode: dev
```

here are some additional resources that led to this approach:

- https://pub.dev/packages/build
- https://pub.dev/packages/build_config
- https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner
- https://github.com/dart-lang/build/tree/master/example
- https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/docs/build_yaml_format.md
- https://pedromarquez.dev/blog/2022/8/flutter-code-gen-1
- https://pedromarquez.dev/blog/2022/9/flutter-code-gen-2
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/5813
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/25487

an alternative approach without a builder can be found here (using the pr #25487 mentioned above):

https://github.com/sestegra/flutter_assets_flavors